# Theorem 7.18 Rudin's

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm studying the example of a continuous function nowhere differentiable on Rudin's book "Principles of Mathematical analysis", but I keep missing the point of an assumption. 
Here you can see the proof.

[image]

The point I'm struggling with is the (?) weird assumption of not allowing any integer lying on the interval (formula n.38).

Intuitively, I see that avoiding an integer on my interval let us evaluate $|\phi(4^n(x+\delta_m))-\phi(4^nx)|$ ($\star$) on a straight line, and the result will be $\frac{1}{2}$.

In the second case, if we have a integer $q$, the graph of the function $\phi$ change the slope in a neighborhood of $q$ (we have something like a $\land$ or $\lor$, with the segments of different measure), but I don't understand whhy in this case the difference ($\star$) change, and why this should be avoid.

I tried to figure it out what's going on here, but I really didn't find anything.

Any hints or solution would be much appreciate, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One wants $\gamma_m$ to be as large as possible: this is exactly the leading term in the crucial inequality at the end. If one allows a “breakpoint” in the middle, it might even become zero (if the breakpoint due to some coincidence lies exactly in between $4^n(x+\delta_m)$ and $4^n x$).
This has to be avoided, because if $\gamma_m$ is too small, it can't become a useful leading term in the inequality, since the things we are subtracting might suddenly get too big.

Comment: I really thank you for the reply, but unfortunately your answer still not clarifies my doubts. In order to accept it, I'd like to see a specific example of the phenomenon you're talking about (that is, a case in which having or not an integer inside the interval changes the result). thanks in advance

Comment: $x=15/16$, $m=1$ yields $|\delta_m|=1/8$, and if one chooses the plus sign, one gets $4^mx=15/4$, $4^m(x+\delta_m)=4^m(15/16+1/8)=17/4$, and thus $\gamma_m=0$.

Comment: I think I'm seeing now what's behind it, I really thank you. Moreover, I see you'r a new contributor, so welcome to mse!